# Jquery Modal Dialog does not load a page

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an html page which has below html content

```
<div id="divBody">
    <input type="text" id="txtUrl" value="http://www.google.com" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnShowPopup" value="Show Popup" onclick="Javascript:ShowPopup();" />
</div>
<div id="divPopup">
</div>
```

I do have a function ShowPopup as below:

```
function ShowPopup() {
    var page = "http://www.google.com";
    $('#divPopup').dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            $(this).load(page);
        },
        close: function(e) {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        },
        height: 625,
        width: 500,
        title: "Test Page"
    });
}
```

I included all the jquery scripts as below:

```
<script src="Scripts/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The title "Test Page" and the Close Button shows up. Why it does not load the google page, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the `open` callback is being invoked?  If so, what DOM element does `$(this)` match?  It might not be the DOM element corresponding to the body of your dialog.

Comment: It is invoked and it does show up the Close button and the title "Test Page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because its a cross domain request. Not sure why your trying to load google's page into a dialog anyways. Loading a page like that can be done using an iFrame (Yes I know they are considered bad). Try loading a page that's on your server.

This might help [cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Looking at the developer tools (F12) for IE I found it is because of cross domain request.

> SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://www.google.com/index.html required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
>
> SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request.
>
> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef1, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef1.

Comment: Sorry, got into a prod issue. Basically, I do have a page where there are different combinations for Product, Rate, APR etc is coming from a different site. For e.g., if the Product is 15 Years, the rate would be say 3.5, APR is 3.625 which is provided by a third party vendor. I will check this and let you know.